# PHP Function vs Echo

Tags: php

I find myself lately working with a ton of tabular data, I am more than comfortable writing the raw html but i'm wondering if there's an easier way (or library worth implementing) that helps reduce time writing html tags such as

```
<tr><td></td></tr>
```

I have created my own custom  function, but I think ultimately it's not necessarily helping and potentially could be slowing down my script, now my project is small so maybe it could cope with that, examples:

```
echo '<tr class="test_class">
    <td>' . $content . '</td>
    <td>' . $second_content . '</td>
<tr/>';
```

here is an example with my current function:

```
tr("test_class");
   td(); echo $content; escape(td);
   td(); echo $second_content; escape(td);
escape(tr);
```

Looking forward to hearing peoples thoughts.

Comment: I recommend changing the 'escape' function name. It's not escaping a td, it's ending or closing the tag. Google 'backslash escape' if you're in doubt about the meaning.

Comment: that doesn't look like you're saving yourself any keystrokes. you're not writing html tags but you're keying in lots of function calls and echo statements. have you considered using zend framework?

Comment: I have thought about the zend framework several times but never seen any solid arguments for any framework, would it help in this situation?

Comment: I would use heredox syntax, that would make at least your example a lot easier to read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this...

1. write your own html helper library, that will contain classes, that can generate html elements based on their data source. For instance you could call them like:

   ```
   <?php
      HtmlHelper::Table("someArrayOfValues", "idOfTable", "styleOfTable");
   ?>
   ```

   This is a good reusable solution, if you implement this idea properly. I was playing with this myself few days ago, really it's simple.
2. if you find 1. difficult, you can split the idea down... But not so deep like you've shown, but generate whole rows instead.

   ```
   <?php
       foreach ($myArray as $key => $value)
       {
            echo HtmlHelper::Row(...);
       }
   ?>
   ```
3. Find some library, that provides this functionality. Can't help you on this one I'm afraid. I like to have control over the generated markup.

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `short_open_tags` turned on (and assuming you can turn it on, if necessary), you can use the templating syntax, like this:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($myList as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $value["key1"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $value["key2"] ?></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

That might make your job easier, in terms of writing tabular data.

Comment: while also making your code more bound to needless environmental constraints.

Comment: While I like the detailed reply I would have to agree, I would never pidgeonhole my code as you never know what system it's going to run on :)

Comment: How is using short_open_tags a needless environmental constraint?

Comment: I see what you mean. There's plenty of ways to turn it on without having to administer the machine itself, like an `.htaccess` file. But, that's assuming you're using Apache. :)

Comment: or you may have to run the code in an environment where you don't have the option to turn it on.

Comment: Well, assuming you can turn it on, that's a nice way of doing it :)

Comment: @MattWhipple This is not an issue. Virtually any part of PHP *may* be disabled on a host, that doesn't mean you should avoid those pieces of the language. You might as well say "I avoid database access, because not every host provides a database". There is absolutely no reason to avoid `<?=` in your templates.

Comment: Thank you @meagar. I personally use that and love it. You can easily avoid using a templating engine that way.

Comment: @SimonGermain PHP *is* a templating engine. What you're avoiding is using a 3rd party templating engine written in a templating engine.

Comment: @meager Most of the lifetime of good code is spent in support.  I'd much rather spend the extra couple minutes and keystrokes in the initial development of code to head off any possible cause of regression or lack of support down the road.  The argument would be more similar to "I use PDO so I don't have to worry about what the DB implementation is".  Even if it _can_ be fixed later, why introduce needless possible points of failure.

Comment: @MattWhipple You're missing the point. There is nothing to fix. If a host doesn't support your code, seek a host that does. Writing bad code to work around a *misconfigured* host is not the answer. And we're not talking about an "extra couple of keystrokes". Short-open-tag is *required* to make PHP a usable templating engine. Using them actively makes code *more* supportable, easier to maintain and far more readable.

Comment: @meagar, that's what I meant by templating engine. I was referring to stuff like Smarty.

Comment: @MattWhipple And if you're worried about short-open-tags, you'd better *stop* using PDO as soon as possible. It's not supported on all servers, specifically those running PHP 4. You should also stop using the GD library, which is commonly missing. If you're going to subscribe to that mentality, the list of features you need to stop using *right now* is very long.

Comment: Another interesting thing to take note is that we're talking about a website here. If the server doesn't fit your architecture, it's your job to make sure it does. When dealing with architectures that uses horizontal scaling, such as websites, making sure all servers support the same configuration is pretty important. Now, if we were talking about an application to be deployed on X number of computers that may or may not have the same stuff configured on them because it's not under your control, I would agree with you that a more generic model is more important. In this case, it's not.

Comment: I follow the concepts of isolating implementation behind contracts/interfaces, and reducing needless coupling.  All of these are intended to make the code as portable as possible and future changes as minimal as possible.  This doesn't apply to all cases or all developers, but as this is a community forum it was intended for a general audience of PHP developers.  I don't have any interest in engaging in a religious war over practices however, especially when terms like _required_ and _bad code_ begin to be thrown around simply because widely used alternatives are disagreed with.

Comment: @MattWhipple You tend to invite argument when you make blanket statements like "while also making your code more bound to needless environmental constraints", which appears to be mindless repetition of an often parroted misconception.

Comment: Alright guys, we're simply stating opinions here. Everyone is free to choose whichever way of doing things they're comfortable with. My answer reflects my own personal preference and beliefs and I was simply suggesting it as a practical way of achieving something. You have the right to agree or disagree with it, that's up to you. But trying to invalidate it because you don't agree is kinda like telling me I'm wrong to dislike tomatoes because tomatoes are delicious. (/metaphore off) :D

Comment: I would recommend that, instead, you post your own answer and explain why it's better to do it your way. That's what makes this site a great resource for the community.

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting that it should be a concern for anyone who may be reading this post.  In a controlled environment for a larger project I would probably use short tags myself as they are now standard in 5.4 (but my PHP work is normally more surgical...and where I can't make such assumptions).  I wasn't inviting argument: I was providing a short, perhaps too strongly worded, caution.  Flamewars don't belong on SO at all.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest strength of PHP for web development is how much its made to do with few calls, and in particular for this case the echoing of content without the need to work through language constraints.  So in general unless the case is really warranted, directly writing the html with the echoes will be the simplest solution that takes the most advantage of PHP, and simplicity is *always* a good thing.

That being said, if you have a lot of complex table generation, then the code would be more readable if use a library like: http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Table/.  Additionally if you were looking to do something like serialize an object into a table display, then creating a serializer that is made for that would be the solution most in-line with the functionality.

In the code above I'd suggest a transparent utility function certainly wouldn't hurt.  But rather than the direction you're going if you consistently have the same number of columns then you could use an array which is joined with the table cell separation markup (a function that produces a row at a time).

Answer (score 0):

it is more comfort to use some template engines. try [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)